# How do I troubleshoot a hanging SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL Server Agent Job with 4 steps.  If I run it, it displays as "Executing" indefinitely.  If I run the code in the four steps sequentially directly into SSMS, they take ~7 seconds to execute.  No configuration information (owner, run as, database, etc.) differs from any other Job that runs normally.  What else can I examine?

Comment: Create logs. (loging procedure for example... With procedure name / step name... ). Log every one statement. Its easier way how to identify problem , also for future, yo can improve every one step separately...

Answer (score 0):

As with any problem that comes in a group, break it down to it's individual parts.  You have run each step separately and you know each individual step works.  Next, add step 1 and 2 and see if it runs.  Next add step 1,2 and 3 and see what happens.  Eliminate all the possible issues step by step.  My guess is that one step is not returning a success and the error logic on it does not say to fail or move to the next step.

Check the properties on each step under advanced and check the On success and On Failure actions.